# How to insert record with proper values in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: c#, boolean, nullable, aspnetboilerplate

I have a columns `FlgStdTest` which is `DEFAULT ((1))` and datatype is `bit`.
I'm trying to insert the record with `FlgStdTest` as `true` or `false`, but its value is always inserted as `true`.

```cs
public async Task<int> CreateTest(TestDetailsDTO input)
{
    int testId = await InsertAndGetIdAsync(ObjectMapper.Map<TestMaster>(input));

    return testId;
}
        
[AutoMap(typeof(TestMaster))]
public class TestDetailsDTO : FullAuditedEntityDto
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public string TestDesc { get; set; }
    public bool FlgStdTest { get; set; }
    public bool FlgActive { get; set; }
}

[Table("TestMaster")]
public class TestMaster: FullAuditedEntity
{
    public const int NVarcharLength20 = 20;
    public const int NVarcharLength50 = 50;

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(NVarcharLength20)]
    public virtual string Test { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(NVarcharLength50)]
    public virtual string TestDesc { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual bool FlgStdTest { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual bool FlgActive { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<TestMaster>(b =>
{
    b.HasIndex(e => new { e.Test, e.IsDeleted }).IsUnique();
    b.Property(e => e.FlgActive).HasDefaultValue(true);
    b.Property(e => e.FlgStdTest).HasDefaultValue(true);
});
```

Request:

```json
{
  "testType": "abc",
  "testDesc": "xyz",
  "flgStdtest": false,
  "flgActive": false,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "deleterUserId": 0,
  "deletionTime": "2017-10-05T10:50:13.956Z",
  "lastModificationTime": "2017-10-05T10:50:13.956Z",
  "lastModifierUserId": 0,
  "creationTime": "2017-10-05T10:50:13.956Z",
  "creatorUserId": 0,
  "id": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Aaron for your suggestion, it has really helped. Read the below paragraph carefully.

> The 'bool' property 'FlgStdTest' on entity type 'TestMaster' is
> configured with a database-generated default. This default will always
> be used when the property has the value 'false', since this is the CLR
> default for the 'bool' type. Consider using the nullable 'bool?' type
> instead so that the default will only be used when the property value
> is 'null'.

I have found a simple workaround to solve my problem, only thing needs to be done is declaring `bool` member as `nullable`.

```cs
[AutoMap(typeof(TestMaster))]
public class TestDetailsDTO : FullAuditedEntityDto
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public string TestDesc { get; set; }
    public bool? FlgStdTest { get; set; }
    public bool? FlgActive { get; set; }
}
    
[Table("TestMaster")]
public class TestMaster: FullAuditedEntity
{
    public const int NVarcharLength20 = 20;
    public const int NVarcharLength50 = 50;
    
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(NVarcharLength20)]
    public virtual string Test { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(NVarcharLength50)]
    public virtual string TestDesc { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public virtual bool? FlgStdTest { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public virtual bool? FlgActive { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Using this new `TestMaster` entities will have `FlgStdTest = null`, not `true` unless drawn from the database. You need `null` checks where appropriate.

Comment: I have not faced any issue, it's all fine. no null check

Answer (score 1):

When you generate the migration, there should have been a warning like:

> The 'bool' property 'FlgStdTest' on entity type 'TestMaster' is configured with a database-generated default. This default will always be used when the property has the value 'false', since this is the CLR default for the 'bool' type. Consider using the nullable 'bool?' type instead so that the default will only be used when the property value is 'null'.

For cases where you want to set a default value for use in existing rows when migrating the database, but don't want EF to use the default value for any newly inserted rows, you can do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestMaster>(b =>
{
    b.HasIndex(e => new { e.Test, e.IsDeleted }).IsUnique();
    b.Property(e => e.FlgActive)
        .HasDefaultValue(true)
        .ValueGeneratedNever();
    b.Property(e => e.FlgStdTest)
        .HasDefaultValue(true)
        .ValueGeneratedNever();
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9291

---

**Update**

> If I don't pass FlgActive and FlgStdTest in request, it inserts false for both the columns, but columns are true by default.

Use auto-property initializers:

```
public class TestDetailsDTO : FullAuditedEntityDto
{
    public bool FlgStdTest { get; set; } = true;
    public bool FlgActive { get; set; } = true;
}

public class TestMaster: FullAuditedEntity
{
    public virtual bool FlgStdTest { get; set; } = true;
    public virtual bool FlgActive { get; set; } = true;
}
```

Comment: it's not working as expected. If I don't pass FlgActive and FlgStdTest in request, it inserts false for both the columns, but columns are true by default